# Why am I receiving 2 emails from my form after I click submit

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with my form. As I click on submit all the details are sent thru my email, but the problem is: I'm receiving 2 emails, 1 in my inbox and one in my spam.

I really don't know where did I go wrong with my code..

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

here is my code for send_app.php

```
<?php

// get posted data into local variables
$EmailFrom = "webmaster";
$EmailTo = "sjb_jparedes@yahoo.com";
$Subject = "Contact us";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$month =$_POST['month'];
$day =$_POST['day'];
$year =$_POST['year'];
$home =$_POST['home'];
$mobile =$_POST['mobile'];
$contact =$_POST['contact'];
$relationship =$_POST['relationship'];
$course =$_POST['course'];
$hours =$_POST['hours'];



// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Month: ";
$Body .= $month;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Day: ";
$Body .= $day;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Year: ";
$Body .= $year;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Home No.: ";
$Body .= $home;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Mobile: ";
$Body .= $mobile;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Contact Person: ";
$Body .= $contact;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Relationship: ";
$Body .= $relationship;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Course: ";
$Body .= $course;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Hours: ";
$Body .= $hours;
$Body .= "\n";

$headers = "From: ".$EmailFrom."" ;

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

// redirect to success page 
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers)){

header( "Location: application.php" );

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: you are sending 2 emails:

```
// First E-Mail
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

// Second E-Mail
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers)){
     header( "Location: application.php" );
}
```

Just delete the first line, or - if you need the return value - write this:

```
// Send E-Mail
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

if ($success){
     header( "Location: application.php" );
}
```

Comment: this has been very help. Thanks you sir!

Comment: @Jonathan: you're welcome ;-) Just accept one of the answers, that's how StackOverflow works [faq]

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're calling `mail` twice in your code:

```
// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

// redirect to success page 
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers)){
```

So of course the mail is sent twice...

Answer (score 1):

You're calling mail twice! Replace this code

```
// redirect to success page 
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers)){
```

with

```
if ($success){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// redirect to success page
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers)){
```

This condition will actually execute another sending, and if successfully then will execute

```
header( "Location: application.php" );
```